# Deploy reports to multiple folders

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I would like to deploy a project with 50 reports to different folders (about 10 folders) in report server from BIDS. The TargetFolder option in project properties is restricting to one folder .I would like to deploy all the reports at one time. Few blogs suggested using VB script to create folders on the fly and deploy reports to respective folders. I am not aware of VB script or the process. Can any only please explain the steps or any alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would create use the VS Configuration Manager (via Project / Properties) to create 10 Configuration entries (copies of your current Config).  Each Configuration would point to a separate folder.

Then to deploy, you can just change the Configuration, right-click the Project (or selected objects) and Deploy.